# .Net Maui WebView behaves differently for iOS and Android

Tags: android, .net, maui

I have a .Net MAUI page which uses the most basic code for a WebView, namely this:

```html
<StackLayout Margin="10">
        <WebView x:Name="wv" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" MinimumHeightRequest="1000" MinimumWidthRequest="20" />
    </StackLayout>
```

In the codebehind there is just a wv.source = url statement.

This displays fine in iOS simulator and on iPhone, ie exactly as if I had entered the URL into Safari on the phone.

On Android it displays as if the website doesn't know the target device size, ie the phone shows a window into a desktop-sized page, but if I enter the URL into the Android Chrome browser, it works fine.

What am I missing?

wv.height and wv.width both show -1 on Android and iOS. DeviceDisplay.Current.MainDisplayInfo.Width and Height both show as expected.

Thanks for any nudges

Comment: If you have control over the website, you can add this line "<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">" it might solve your issue. If you don't have access to the website, you can create a handler for a custom webView and in there you can append this line onto the website you are loading.

Comment: Thank you. I have no control over the website, although it does seem to be website-related in that other sites look fine in the webview control. I find it strange that it works fine via the browser on Android though, and vie the simulator in iOS. Will attempt to work out how to do what you suggest! YOu wouldn't happen to have an example would you?!

Comment: I just found another post with instructions to do this, when searching based on your response - many thanks!

Comment: Finally I've got around this via creating a custom WebView and adding the following code:
     Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.WebViewHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping("MyCustomization", (Handler, View) =>
            {
                if (View is CustomWebView)
                {
#if ANDROID
              Handler.PlatformView.Settings.UseWideViewPort = true;
              Handler.PlatformView.Settings.LoadWithOverviewMode= true;
              Handler.PlatformView.Settings.BuiltInZoomControls=true;
              Handler.PlatformView.Settings.SetSupportZoom(true);
#endif
                }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, according to your comment, as an answer:

It can be solved by customizing the WebView using Handlers to call platform-specific code.

```cs
Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.WebViewHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping
("MyCustomization", (Handler, View) => {

        if (View is CustomWebView)
        {
#if ANDROID 
            Handler.PlatformView.Settings.UseWideViewPort = true;
            Handler.PlatformView.Settings.LoadWithOverviewMode = true;
            Handler.PlatformView.Settings.BuiltInZoomControls = true;
            Handler.PlatformView.Settings.SetSupportZoom (true);
#endif
        }

})
```

Get official doc: [Customize a specific control instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/handlers/customize?view=net-maui-8.0#customize-a-specific-control-instance) for more details.